# A problem with the pst-intersect package

Tags: pstricks

Can you tell me about the difference between two the following codes?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-func,pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pst-intersect}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,5)
\pssavebezier[plotpoints=1000,linecolor=DOrange, arrows=->]{A}%
                    (0,0)(0,5)(5,5)(5,1)(1,1.5)
\pssavebezier[arrows=->,plotpoints=1000]{B}(0,5)(0,0)(5,0)(5,5)(0,2)
\psintersect[name=C, showpoints]{A}{B}
\color{DOrange}
```

the first code ( I will choose it):

```
\uput[150](C1){1}
\uput[85](C2){2}
\uput[-20](C4){3}
\uput[90](C3){4}
```

the second code (I won't choose it):

```
\uput[150](!\psGetIsectCenter{C}{A}{1} I-C1.x I-C1.y){1}
\uput[85](!\psGetIsectCenter{C}{A}{2} I-C2.x I-C2.y){2}
\uput[-20](!\psGetIsectCenter{C}{A}{3} I-C3.x I-C3.y){3}
\uput[90](!\psGetIsectCenter{C}{A}{4} I-C4.x I-C4.y){4}
```

The result of two above codes as the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `\uput[150](C1){1}` is like going to US from Europe through the North pole.
- `\uput[150](!\psGetIsectCenter{C}{A}{1} I-C1.x I-C1.y){1}` is like going to US from Europe through the South pole.

Both are correct but the former is more compact and the latter is unnecessarily complicated. You need the latter if you want to do some calculation with, for example, the abscissa of an intersection point.

For example, adding 1 to `I-C1.x` as follows.

```
\uput[150](!\psGetIsectCenter{C}{A}{1} I-C1.x 1 add I-C1.y){1}
```

Comment: "Upvoting" and "accepting" are independent events that are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Wry smile :-)))